Unity Physics Collisions Happening Despite Being Disabled in Collision Matrix
I've got a weird issue in my game where a collision is happening DESPITE that specific interaction between the two layers being disabled in the Collision Matrix (images attached).

The Projectile is on the PlayerProjectile layer.
The NPC/Entity is split thus:

Capsule Collider (Layer EntityMovement) for colliding with ground, etc
Unity Primitives with their own colliders (Layer NPC) for hit detection etc



I have the following code used to debug as well:
    protected void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log($"Collision between {LayerMask.LayerToName(gameObject.layer)} and {LayerMask.LayerToName(collision.gameObject.layer)}");
    }

The output is

Collision between PlayerProjectile and EntityMovement

but this should be disabled.
I have checked and double checked the layers on the objects in question, and they are correct/as intended.
My game object setup is probably a bit complex but when boiled down, this seems like it should be simple, yet for some reason it doesn't work.
What am I missing?




What objects contain the colliders? I can see that the SandCrab object has a collider, but are you sure that the projectile contains a collider as this is not visible in your screenshots? It may be that the child object of the projectile is the one with the collider, and this may not be on the PlayerProjectile layer.

The green line in the screenshot of the projectile is the collider (capsule collider). The child has no collider, as this setup means the model can be whatever I want without affecting collision.
I have now stumbled randomly on an answer that I've tested through experimentation, but I'm not sure if said fix is the best solution.

check the hierarchy. if the object you given the collider doesn't have a rigidbody attached, then it will go to the parents and looks for the rigidbodies. check if the layer set on the rigidbody in parent is what you expect it to be.
if you want children have a different layer then you have three options
1- give all of the children rigidbodies
2- make an object in the same position of parents and make all of the colliders children of that. then write a code to fix the position of this object as the parent
3- make a parent for all the children under your rigidbody and give a rigidbody to that.

I stumbled across an answer on the following site, posted by user hippocoder, which I have now confirmed through my own experimentation.
how does unity prioritize collisions on a hierarchy?
All child objects, if they have a collider but NO rigidbody of their own, will register their collision at the first rigidbody-attached collider in their (tree?) of parents. In my case, this means that the projectile wasn't colliding with the EntityMovement as such, it was colliding with what it should, but registering it on the SandCrab object (as opposed to, say, Head).
To fix this, I attached a rigidbody on each of the children, and set them to kinematic (since none of these rigidbody components will ever move themselves with physics) and now the collision reads correctly.
That being said, I have no idea if there is a better solution (seems like there should be . . .?) but this is what works

What you want to check should be collision.collider.gameObject.layer. collision.collider is the collider colliding with your projectile, and collision.gameObject refers to the game object the rigidbody is attached on.
Sidenote: actually you are making compound colliders, so you'd better follow Unity's practice:

A compound collider is made of the following elements:

A parent GameObject that has a Rigidbody
Empty child GameObjects that contain colliders


